# How did a 14 year old get elected Queen?

Tags: star-wars

Queen Amidala was an elected Queen at age 14. Despite the fact that she had participated in the Legislative Youth program, and she wasn't the youngest queen ever, it still seems quite young... How could this happen?

Comment: Obviously she ran on a sensible platform and argued for some sound policies.

Comment: If you can be *elected* at age 14, I have to imagine you are also allowed to *vote* at age 14. My theory is that she ran on a pro-Bieber platform and locked up the teen girl demographic.

Comment: Maybe she ran on an anti-Gungan campaign.

Comment: She was elected by receiving the necessary majority of ballots.

Comment: @All: Smart alecks;-)

Comment: Everyone on Naboo is Force Sensitive, and they knew she'd grow up to be Natalie Portman.

Comment: She murdered her predecessor by drinking her through a straw.

Comment: Clearly it's because if she'd been a more sensible age like 25 or 30 it would have made her eventual copulation with a seven-year-old boy who she first met as a fully grown monarch **way** more creepy, and obviously not having a little kid Anakin was simply an unacceptable option to Lucas, because the only way to create sympathy for a character is to make them cute and innocent.

Comment: @Oghma  - what was that in reference to?

Comment: @DVK It was an episode of Futurama where Fry accidentally drank the king of a planet occupied by liquid beings, and their laws dictated that the person that killed the king would be the next king.

Comment: Perhaps their years are longer than ours, and her 14 is our 28?

Comment: @Wikis: No, our years are almost exactly the same length. According to [Galactic Standard Calendar](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_Standard_Calendar) on the Wookieepedia: "The calendar was based on the size and rotation of the planet Coruscant. ... Each day consisted of 24 standard hours. A standard week was 5 standard days, and each month was seven weeks (making 35 standard days each month). A standard year was 368 days, composed of ten months, three fete weeks, and three holidays."

Comment: Queens are elected?

Comment: [Royal elections in Poland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_elections_in_Poland)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Much of this is based off of [this article](http://anneke.bakadeshiproductions.com/starwars/padmeFAQ.html#question23), as well as [this Wookieepedia article](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Padm%C3%A9_Amidala).

Basically, she was trained much like the royalty of old to rule from a young age, through methods such as the Young Legislative Program, and the Apprentice Legislature program. She rose quickly through the program, becoming a full Apprentice Legislator at only age 11. She had become the Princess of Theed, basically the mayor of the capital of Naboo, at only age 13.

The previous King, Veruna, was very unpopular, as opposed to Amidala. She went through many debates, winning them all. She traveled to the people, really getting to know them, both listening and speaking, and ultimately won by an overwhelming majority.

Comment: I prefer the *Darths and Droids* version, where large portions of Naboo are made up on the spot by an 8-year-old girl.

Comment: Seems more plausible :)

Comment: The royalty of old weren't trained to rule at all, for the most part.